# Why is "./" used when executing a program?

Tags: linux, bash

If I have a program named foo, why do I need to say ./foo and not simply foo? Doesn't ./ just mean within the current directory?

Comment: Because `./` is not in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type in just a command – eg. `foo` – the shell (usually `bash`) will only look for it in certain directories – like /bin, /usr/bin, /usr/X11R6/bin and so on.  It will typically *not* look in your "current directory" (ie. "." ) because of security concerns (*especially* if you're **root**).  If "." is added, it should be added to *the end of* the search-path.

If you want to run a executable that's *not* in this search-path, you need to specify the whole absolute or relative path to the command.  For example:

```
/home/bok/foo   # Absolute in my homedir

~/src/bar  # Shorthand for my homedir and a subdir in it

../Download/foobar  # Relative path – up one step, then down in Download
```

Or – if the command is in my current directory – simply add a `./`:

```
./foo
```

The search-path for `bash` is stored in the **PATH** environmental-variable, so you can see it by typing:

```
echo $PATH
```

To add "." – which you really *shouldn't* do – type:

```
export PATH="$PATH:."
```

The PATH is searched in order, so if there are several executables with the same name in different directories, it's the one in the directory first in the PATH that the shell will execute.

First after looking in all the listed directories, will you get a "command not found" error.

+++

The problem with adding the current directory – `.` – to the PATH, is that you don't really know if an executable in a "non standard" directory you may just happen to be in should be executed or not.

Lets say I'm evil an make a destructive program that delete as many files as possible and leave it in my home directory – or worse, in /tmp... I call this program `sl` – a common miss-type of `ls` – and wait.

Some random user is in /tmp, and miss-spells `ls` with `sl`.  With a normal PATH – without . – nothing happens, except he gets an error for "command not found".  If he got '.' at the end of his PATH, then he won't get an error for typing the command.  Instead my `sl` command will run, and delete all the files he owns.  If he happens to be **root**, the command will be able to delete much of the system.  (This is why **root** *really should* make it a rule to *always* use the *full path* of commands, rather than trusting PATH.)

If he had placed '.' first in his PATH and I made program called `ls` (correct spelling) and put it in a directory, then it would be *my* program – not the normal `ls` – that would be run if he typed `ls` in that directory.  Because `bash` would look in the current directory (.) *first* – before looking in the system-directories with the genuine `ls`.